# Distribution of n indistinguishable balls in k compartments which are distinguishable?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The question like in the title. I've found the formula in a book to solve this problem but unfortunately, don't know where does it come from, because it doesn't have anything with the known formulas in combinatorics. It is: ${n+k-1 \choose n}$.

Comment: See [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: @lulu thanks a lot. That's exactly what I was looking for.